# Как создать триальный компонент

Tags: delphi, защита, компоненты

Делаю свой компонент на Delphi, он будет триальным.
Нужно, чтобы перед запуском приложения выводилось сообщение 
вида 
`MessageDlg( 'В приложении используется триальный компонент (имя компонента)', mtWarning, [ mbOK ], 0 );`.
Как это реализовать?
Если можно, примерчик.

Пробовал делать так:

```
initialization
 begin
   MessageDlg( 'В приложении используется триальный компонент (имя компонента)',     mtWarning, [ mbOK ], 0 );
 end;
```

Работает, но при размещении на форму второго компонента Delphi выдает ошибку и виснет.

Сделал по-другому, вот так:

protected

```
{ Protected declarations }
  procedure Loaded; override;
 //******************
procedure TMyComponent.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
   MessageDlg( 'В приложении используется триальный компонент (имя компонента)', mtWarning, [ mbOK ], 0 );
end;
```

Comment: добавьте подобное в [секцию](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa051199.htm) `initialization`.

Comment: в конструкторе это можно добавить, а чтоб в ide не сыпались msgdlg проверять на csDesigning in ComponentState...